# 49" TV wall mount with full motion bracket on plasterboard

Tags: drywall, walls, studs, brackets, television

I recently purchased the LG 49SJ800V. I would like to wall mount this TV using a full motion TV bracket (like [this](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Invision%C2%AE-Ultra-Strong-Bracket-Mount-Black/dp/B01AYBLPNA/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1504878052&sr=8-1&keywords=invision)). Aerial and electricity sockets are located at 1.83m from the floor on a plasterboard. The first thing I did was to search for the stud using the Bosch Truvo. Yet I could not find any. I then opened the socket to check whether I could spot the stud from there. But, I could only see a quite thick plasterboard (see pic) and a gap between a wall made of bricks and the plasterboard. The socket were screwed over an horizontal piece of wood possibly attached to the brick wall.

Given that TV weights about 13kg (about 29 pounds) and that the plasterboard is quite thick, I was hoping that 6 spring toggles would do the work. However, after some search on the internet, it seems that a number of people advises not to wall mount a TV with a full motion bracket without fixing the bracket to the stud.

Any advise on this regard?

[image]

Comment: I don't see how spring toggles would work here anyway. You don't seem to have the required clearance. That said, the wallboard must be fastened to something. You might end up drilling a series of holes to figure out what.

Comment: a strong tiny magnet on a string should (eventually) find the nails holding the drywall to the stud.

Comment: Thanks, I will search again for the stud. Could it be possible that the plasterboard is mounted with no stud given that it is between two windows that are about 1.40m from each other?

Comment: A span of 1.4m is way to big to consider not using a stud, especially on an exterior wall.  I'm not sure what the standard stud spacing is in metric, but in the US, its 16 inches, and in some cases 24", but you'd have to have a particularly negligent framing contractor to try anything over 24".

Comment: I just opened another electric socket. it seems that the plasterboard is an insulated one (there is thick layer made of something similar to a dense sponge). I updated the picture to give you an idea. I cannot see anything behind because of the very narrow gap.